# How do I profile applications on Windows and Linux to get CPU and RAM usuage values?

Tags: java, linux, windows, profiling, monitoring

I am busy doing some research and I need to do a comparison between two methods of system monitoring. I have to compare the total memory of overhead and computation required when queries are made to an external software package (i.e one that I did not create but running on the same system) as well the overhead in my software package (written in JAVA) when including all the libraries and making all the queries.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can approach this task to achieve these goals? Are there any general profiling solutions available that just "plug" into your system monitor and retrieve the system statistics this way? Or just a pointer in the right direction would be more than helpful right now as I am completely stuck :/

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [VisualVM](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/intro.html) (For sure in Windows, but don't know about Linux) (or) You can write a simple program using [JMX API](https://blogs.oracle.com/theshortenspot/entry/jmx_based_monitoring_-_part_tw).

Comment: So I ended up using a combination of JProfiler and VisualVM. I was continuously running into an issue where VisualVM would crash when trying to profile the CPU. JProfiler gave me the data that I needed with ease. The only problem is that its only free for 10 days. :/